# Change CF7 status dynamically

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, contact-form-7

I'm trying to alter the status of the Contact Form 7 result after an API call so I can return an error on the front end if required (ie by default this should show a red error under the form, from the ajax response)

I'm using the **Forms3rdPartyIntegration** plugin, but this just gives me a callback hook where I can then try and change the CF7 output (https://github.com/zaus/forms-3rdparty-integration)

As far as I can see the CF7 status is read only? I can't see a way to stop CF7 just giving a mail_sent_ok status

```
add_action('Forms3rdPartyIntegration_service', array(&$this, 'service_callback'), 10, 2);

public function service_callback($response, $results) {        

    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $cf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

    // check for errors (code omitted)
    // this is what I am essentially trying to do
    // but doesn't work
    $submission->status = 'mail_failed'
    $cf7->skip_mail = true;

    ...
}
```

I'd be grateful if anyone had any pointers on triggering a CF7 fail response.

This appears to be a similar issue
[wordpress invalidate cf7 after api call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774134/wordpress-invalidate-cf7-after-api-call)

Comment: Try something similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774134/wordpress-invalidate-cf7-after-api-call/49243202#49243202

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone who encounters this question, I think you are looking for this:

```
if(your_condition) {
    add_filter("wpcf7_ajax_json_echo", function ($response, $result) {
        $response["status"] = "mail_sent_ng";
        $response["message"] = "Validation errors occurred. Please confirm the fields and submit it again.";
        return $response;
    });
}
```

This gives the status `mail_sent_ng` instead of `mail_ok_sent`.

Also `$response["message"]` sets the error/ajax message that is shown to user.

Since you already had `$cf7->skip_mail = true` in your code, you have stopped the mail from sending, and with the code above, you have shown the user that there was an error.

You can also use status `validation_error`.